# How to debug org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4?

Tags: java, xml, validation, schema

(not it may not be related but today I just got Caused by: `java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UTF_8` and same with Oxygen XML editor)

The error is:

```
SEVERE: null    
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'file:/fileLocation', because 1) 
could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element
of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

Coming from third line of code of this:

```
File schemaFile = new File("filenName.xsd");
            SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
```

The first thing I did was to copy the path and test it to make sure it pointed to the correct file. I did.

Second was checking if java was able to read the file, and I checked by using .canRead();

Third I check inside the schema for the root node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF_8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="name" xmlns="name">
     ...
</xsd:schema>
```

It used to be **xs:schema**, but i switch it because I got this error. The strangest part is that when i coded that I didn't get any errors (1 week ago).

Answer (score 4):

Of course `UTF_8` is incorrect, it should be `UTF-8`

There's an explanation of what valid `encoding` atrribute values are in XML declaration here http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-EncodingDecl

In practice, Java XML parsers support any `encoding` that Java supports, and also allow aliases, eg UTF8 is good too, but not UTF_8.

Comment: Replace all problem, but still cant figure why a small - _ makes Oxygen and Netbeans crash. (now they dont)